# Typescript keep subdirectories while building

Tags: typescript

I have been following the tutorials to try to get Typescript working with Angular 2.  The problem is that I cannot seem to compile subdirectories and preserve the subdirectories.

My tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "build",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "sourceRoot": "src",

        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": false

    },
    "exclude": [
        "build",
        "client",
        "GulpTasks",
        "node_modules",
        "typings"
    ]
}
```

Now my source code has different modules and client/server folders for the project.

```
+build
+node_modules
+src
 ---+client
      ---+dir1
         ---+file1.ts
      ---+dir2
 ---+server
    ---+file1.ts
+typings
```

I need to preserve the directory structure when compiling, but files found in the subdirectory (src/server) do not preserve the server subdirectory folder when moved into the build folder. There is not a build/server/file1.js, but it is just build/file1.js.

How can you configure tsc to move files with the subdirectory when writing the JS files?  I have some files in the src/client/dir1 that have the same name as the server/dir1 files and cannot have one overwrite the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you should set 'rootDir' to get desired effect and use at least typescript 1.7.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "build",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",

        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": false

    },
    "exclude": [
        "build",
        "client",
        "GulpTasks",
        "node_modules",
        "typings"
   ]
}
```

See the following issue at github: [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5134)